# Traveling from New York city to Starkville Mississippi with public transport

Tags: usa, public-transport, mississippi

I was looking for cheap ways to get from New York to Starkville Mississippi. I have seen flight but they are at least 350
I found a bus from New York to Atlanta GA for $50 but I don't knkw what to do next cna someone please tell me if there are any public transports available

Comment: Greyhound apparently serves the towns of Tupelo and Durant, MS, each about an hour from Starkville, but not Starkville itself.

Comment: [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/New-York/Starkville) has nothing closer than Atlanta

Comment: Google maps can’t find a way there by public transport, and Rome2Rio gets to Tupelo and then tells you to drive. It looks like options are limited indeed.

Comment: I’m quite amazed that this the location of Mississippi State University and despite local public transport, there doesn’t seem to be any way to get there other than by car or plane. Weird.

Comment: http://mdot.ms.gov/connectms/ suggests that this part of the state is served by a transit agency called "EZTAG", but I cannot find a website for this agency.  It does list a phone number, (601) 650-7484.

Comment: There’s a bus from the airport, and there’s a $20 shuttle from Columbus MS but it’s likewise apparently impossible to get there via public transport. An Uber from Tupelo is about $100. Maybe you could look up ride share on Craigslist or something similar? Looks like trying to optimise the flight may be the most sensible option (don’t forget the bus or train will take you around 20 hours).

Comment: @jcaron It's not that weird. It's a rural, undeveloped area of a rural, undeveloped state. Starkville is a much smaller town than, for example, Tuscaloosa, and unlike Tuscaloosa, there are no interstate highways nearby. For school breaks, there will be charter buses that take students to this or that corner of the state. Otherwise, it's a small population heading to Starkville who would take a bus rather than fly or drive in their own car. FWIW, Oxford, MS, home to the other major state university in Mississippi, doesn't have intercity bus service either.

Comment: @choster Do you have pointers to such charter buses? Don’t know if OP is going there as a student at the start of a term or for some other reason, but in the former case that would definitely help them.

Comment: @jcaron I'm not, unfortunately, but it's commonplace for express buses to run on specific dates to take advantage of the extremely concentrated student demand at times like Thanksgiving. In New York, for example, a company called College Express runs buses on a couple of days a semester to various campuses upstate, but they only advertise locally.

Answer (score 6):

The problem with getting to and from Starkville is the so-called last mile, or in this case, the last 20 or 200. The one and only time I went there, I literally hitchhiked in from Memphis and also hitchhiked out (to Birmingham). I presume you don't want to do this, but it is the cheapest way in. Starkville hasn't had scheduled intercity bus service in years. It's important to remember that despite the presence of a major state university, this area is extremely rural and is a very long distance from any large city.

The nearest airport with commercial service is Golden Triangle Regional Airport (KGTR) in Columbus, about 20 miles east. The Starkville-MSU SMART bus has a free [Airport Express](https://www.smart.msstate.edu/schedule-and-routes/gtr-express/) with its schedule synchronized to the flight schedule of the only commercial flights into and out of GTR, a Delta Connection to/from ATL. So if you want to fly in here it's going to be on SkyTeam. It's also going to be expensive. The lowest JFK-GTR one-way I found for next week was $462 on August 10.

By comparison, a Delta JFK-ATL flight on August 10 was $169. Combined with a [Friendly City airport shuttle](https://friendlycityexpress.com/shop/) from ATL to Starkville, which is $200 plus [tip](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/14109/3221), you save a few bucks, and possibly save a long layover at ATL. Friendly City also will shuttle to Birmingham ($165) and Memphis ($200), but flights into those cities were significantly more expensive than into ATL so I didn't bother looking further.